# Tool for upgrading project to VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, csproj

There are descriptions on Web how to migrate your projects in **VS2015** or earlier to new **VS2017** template.

But is there a tool that has already automated that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is OpenSource https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017 that is doing exactly this.